# Send data via '.getJson' in jQuery and retrive on 'PHP' File

Tags: php, jquery

So i want to **send a variable to my php page and output appropriate json there based on the data.**
THis is what i did.I am new to jquery but have done php

```
                $(function() {

        $("#json-one").change(function() {

            var dropdown = $(this);
        var name=dropdown.val();
            $.getJSON("categories_php?name=",{ "name": name }, 
       function(data) {

            prompt(data.name);
                            var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
                $jsontwo.append("<option>" + data.name + "</option>");          



            });
        });

    });
```

on the php page for test i have not done much

```
    <?php
    $m=new Mongo();
    $db=$m->admin;
    $collection=$db->categories;
    $cur=$collection->find();
    $name['name']= $_REQUEST['name'];
    print_r(json_encode($name));
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
 $.getJSON("categories_php",{ name: name }, function() {
      //Some code
 });
```

Comment: used that too no luck

Comment: umm..the url is correct but i forgot the extension .php